# filter vid multiple conditions

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with data 0,1,2,3,A,B,C,! arranged in a matrix-style like this

```
0,1,A,!
3,B,1,2
0,0,A,B
```

For each row I would like to count the number of 0 and A, resulting in this

```
0,1,A,! => 2
3,B,1,2 => 0
0,0,A,B => 3
```

I've tried COUNTA in combination with FILTER, which works fine when using a single condition, like

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:D1;A1:D1=0))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:D1;A1:D1="A"))
```

but when combining them to `=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:D1;A1:D1=0;A1:D1="A"))` I get an error. I've played around with `=QUERY` but no success

Answer (score 0):

One option may be:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNA(FILTER(A1:D1, A1:D1 = 0)), 0, COUNTA(FILTER(A1:D1, A1:D1 = 0))) + IF(ISNA(FILTER(A1:D1, A1:D1 = "A")), 0, COUNTA(FILTER(A1:D1, A1:D1 = "A"))))
```